# Find simple polygon with most guards outside of it

Tags: computational-geometry, polygons

I’ve been researching an optimal strategy of playing in mobile game of Ingress and came up with an interesting (for me) computational geometry problem.

Statement of the problem: You’re given N distinct points on plane, and number M < N. Find a simple polygon with M vertices out of the given N points, that maximizes number of points outside of the polygon such that each can see all of the polygon’s vertices.

The problem seems related to vertex guarding of polygons and perhaps to weakly visible polygons, but it's different from any problem I’ve managed to find in the literature.

Have you heard about a research about a similar problem?
I'd be especially interested if there is possibility of any polynomial time solution or approximation.

Best!

Example image: black and red points are the N input points, blue polygon is the (maybe) optimal polygon with m=24 vertices, and red points are the points which can see all of polygon's verties.
[image]